# Структуры как поля / свойства класса

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Известно, что структуры - это значимые типы, а значит передаются по значению. И это становится проблемой, когда хочется использовать готовые структуры как поля или свойства классов. С ними становится невозможно работать, так при попытке изменить какие-то поля в структуре (которое является свойством или полем), компилятор кричит об ошибке.

В принципе ничего удивительного, это ожидаемое поведение, вызывающему коду отправляется копия структуры и компилятор дает понять, что ты изменишь копию, но это ни на что не повлияет. Это понятно, но как быть?

Приведу пример:

```
class Hero
{
  // Структура-поле
  public Point Coordinates;

  public Hero
  {
    Coordinates = new Point(0,0);
  }
}
```

В данном случае, изменить Coordinates.X из внешнего кода будет невозможно.
Какова практика работы со структурами как полями / свойствами? На вышеуказанном примере, как изменить структуру?

Comment: А зачем его менять из внешнего кода?

Comment: @Grundy ну примеров может быть масса, вот например в случае что я описал, допустим, нам надо изменить координаты героя. Или еще банальнее, есть у нас поле типа Color, хотим изменять цвет чего-то там.

Comment: Тут все зависит от конкретного примера, как сказал в своем ответе @VladD, пример из вопроса должен работать ожидаемым образом

Comment: Ждём return by ref... Но они ведь не сделают...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде [работают же](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3A%22New%20Language%20Feature%20-%20Ref%20Locals%20and%20Returns%22%20).

Comment: @VladD, чего-то я проворонил, похоже... Последнее время не очень за шарпом слежу. А можно ссылку на пример кода? И, кстати, разве это не ответ на этот вопрос тогда?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/280978/

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно, хорошая статья, я и не знал. Там ещё кодогенераторы должны подвезти, будет не платформа, а сказка. думаю, что и в VB добавят.

Comment: Кстати про VB... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554570/178988 - что не так??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, для полей значимых типов вы работаете с самим полем, так что вот такое должно работать ожидаемым образом:

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
hero.Coordinates.X = 100;
```

Но правильнее выставлять вместо поля свойство, и вот там уже вы и правда работаете с копией:

```
class Hero
{
    public Point Coordinates { get; set; }

    public Hero()
    {
        Coordinates = new Point(0,0);
    }
}
```

В этом случае имеет смысл присваивать значение целиком:

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
hero.Coordinates = new Point(100, 0);
```

---

*Дополнение* (из дискуссии с автором вопроса в комментариях): для того, чтобы пользователям вашего класса не приходилось думать о таких тонкостях, имеет смысл сделать структуру иммутабельной (то есть, запретить изменять её поля по отдельности), и определить в вашем классе setter (то есть, свойство с акцессором `set`) для структуры или её частей, который правильно изменит значение. Таким образом, компилятор предотвратит возможную ошибку пользователей вашего класса.

Comment: или вообще не пробрасывать его наружу и работать с ним только внутри класса :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, если это UI-объект, то его координаты обычно нужно задавать снаружи, так что это валидный юзкейс.

Comment: @VladD "Для начала, для полей значимых типов вы работаете с самим полем, так что вот такое должно работать ожидаемым образом" понятно, есть какое-то объяснение почему все происходит именно так? Почему когда через свойство, то передается по значению, а через поле, то по ссылке?

Comment: @YesMan: Поле не «передаётся по ссылке». Вы просто работаете с _самим_ полем, lvalue в терминах C++. А вот геттер свойства — это обыкновенная функция, а значит, как и любая функция, он всегда возвращает копию значения для значимых типов (и копию ссылки для ссылочных типов).

Comment: @VladD Извините, что тянул с отметкой правильного ответа 3 года :) Разве что я бы дополнил, что если уж так случилось, что полем типа является структура, то лучше ей определить свойство с аксессором set и там явно определить логику присваивания, чтобы потребителям этого поля не приходилось вникать в тонкости присваивания ему значения.

Comment: @YesMan: Это да, хорошая идея! Если возможно, имеет смысл не делать в структуре (открытых) мутирующих методов/аксессоров, чтобы пользователь был вынужден делать правильно, через создание новой структуры. Сейчас подправлю ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Структуры обычно нужны для того, чтобы получить возможность выполнить одну операцию, например сравнения или присваивания, над группой данных, в том числе разнородных. Я не хочу сказать что структуры нужно списать в архив, просто многие задачи, которые решались и решаются с помощью структур в других языках, в C# более успешно решают полноценные классы.

В исходном коде класса **[System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,16f3a97c67aba8b8)**, можно посмотреть реализацию свойства `Size`, как пример того, как Microsoft использует структуры.

У контрола есть поля `width` и `height`. Одноименные свойства `Width` и `Height` и свойство `Size`, которое возвращает значения `width` и `height` в виде одной структуры типа `System.Drawing.Size`. Для изменений размеров у вас есть целых два пути: задать ширину и высоту отдельно через соответствующие свойства, либо установить оба размера сразу с помощью структуры `Size`, например скопированной из другого контрола.

Если рассмотреть свойство `Location`, то найти отдельные свойства для X и Y не получится, их просто нет, хотя внутри используются отдельные поля x и y для хранения координат. В принципе, можно было и внутри использовать структуру, т.к. координаты точки довольно редко используются по-отдельности.

На мой взгляд - это достаточно неплохой пример практического применения структур с учетом их особенностей.

У Microsoft есть и менее удачные примеры, например свойство `Control.Font`, в котором кажется довольно странным, не иметь возможности указать, например атрибут шрифта `Bold` без замены всей структуры `Font`, но если внимательно присмотреться к [исходникам](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9df809cb5bb5d985) можно заметить, что это свойство связано с неуправляемым кодом `WinAPI` и скорее всего особого выбора не было, не считая конечно нереального на практике варианта "быстренько запилить новый API".

Применяйте имеющиеся инструменты по назначению (в разных языках оно может быть разным, это нормально).