# Не компилируется Await в Catch и Finally

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, async-await

Visual Studio 2015. Если пишу код на C#, то всё работает:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    this.Text = "Text from try";
    throw new Exception();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    this.Text = "Text from catch";
  }
  finally
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    this.Text = "Text from finally";
  }
}
```

А вот если на VB.NET, то получаю ошибку компиляции:

> Error BC36943 'Await' cannot be used inside a 'Catch' statement, a 'Finally' statement, or a 'SyncLock' statement.

```vb
Public Class Form1
  Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
      Await Task.Delay(1000)
      Me.Text = "Text from Try"
      Throw New Exception()
    Catch ex As Exception
      Await Task.Delay(1000)
      Me.Text = "Text from Catch"
    Finally
      Await Task.Delay(1000)
      Me.Text = "Text from Finally"
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Почему не компилируется? Я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: `await` в `catch` [появился только в C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156499.aspx) — может, в VB [ещё не подвезли](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2.aspx)?

Comment: @VladD, они же обещали новые фичи одновременно добавлять? Или всё-таки нет? :(

Comment: Ну, например фильтры в catch в VB были давно, я обзавидовался, пока они наконец в C# добавили. Мы для этих целей как-то даже специально модуль на VB писали. // Они стараются одновременно, но судя по всему не успели в прошлом релизе.

Comment: @VladD, там очень многое из 6го шарпа было давно. Например, using static и инициализация свойств (обычных). А что делать, если мне нужен await в catch или finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, в текущую версию VB фича «`await` в `catch`/`finally`» [не успела пробиться](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/256), её обещают в следующей версии.

Для текущей версии можно применить грязный некрасивый ручной путь, который у меня работал на C# 5.

Код

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (SomeException ex)
{
    await CatchTask();
    if (cond)
        throw;
}
finally
{
    await FinallyTask();
}
```

переписывается в виде

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.ExceptionServices
```

```vb
Dim exinfo As ExceptionDispatchInfo = Nothing
Dim needCatch As Boolean = False

Try
    ' ...
Catch ex As Exception
    exinfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex)
    needCatch = TypeOf ex Is SomeException
End Try

If needCatch Then
    Await CatchTask()
    If Not cond Then exinfo = Nothing
End If

Await FinallyTask()
If exinfo IsNot Nothing Then exinfo.Throw()
```

`ExceptionDispatchInfo` нужно, чтобы сохранять правильный стек в исключении.

Для случая, когда нету `throw`, `catch` или `finally`, код можно довольно сильно упростить.

Comment: Хм.. Ручная диспетчеризация исключения :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, закат солнца вручную. :-\

Comment: Какой-то у тебя неправильный finally - если исключение будет не SomeException, то он пойдёт лесом...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно! Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вот вроде бы финальный вариант, проверяй логику.

Comment: Ну почти :) Потерялось `needRethrow = True` в `Catch ex As Exception`. Ну и всегда есть вариант поизвращаться и вместо исключения бросить какую-то гадость из il-кода.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Но у меня ж `Dim needRethrow As Boolean = True`

Comment: А если исключение не возникло, а needRethrow = True? Получается, надо False в конце Try? Ну или проверить exinfo перед выбрасыванием.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно! Кстати, может, объединиь catch-блоки и тестировать через `is`?

Comment: Да, вариант. А то всё равно они ничего какие-то пустые.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Очередной финальный вариант

Comment: Зря не используешь однострочные if'ы и присваивание условий булам. А по логике - вроде всё хорошо. Хотя, я ещё не пробовал это компилировать :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я ж не очень в синтаксисе. Может, подправь? Я заодно чему-то научусь тоже.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43835/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).